# How can I make a composite unique constraint with foreign keys and regular keys in Sequelize?

Tags: node.js, sqlite, foreign-keys, sequelize.js, unique-constraint

We have two models, users and items.  Under User.js

```
User = Model.define('User', {
    id: {
        type: DataType.UUID,
        defaultValue: DataType.UUIDV1,
        primaryKey: true,
    },
});
```

And under Item.js

```
Item = Model.define('Item', {
    id: {
        type: DataType.UUID,
        defaultValue: DataType.UUIDV1,
        primaryKey: true,
    },
});
```

Here is their association, a user can have many items.

```
User.hasMany(Items, {
    foreignKey: {
        allowNull: false,
        name: 'itemId',
    },
    onUpdate: 'cascade',
    onDelete: 'cascade',
});
```

Assume that each user may only have one of each type of item.  **How do I add a unique constraint for this?**  The following code does not work.

```
User.hasMany(Items, {
    foreignKey: {
        allowNull: false,
        name: 'itemId',
        unique: 'userItemUnique',
    },
    onUpdate: 'cascade',
    onDelete: 'cascade',
});

Item = Model.define('Item', {
    id: {
        type: DataType.UUID,
        defaultValue: DataType.UUIDV1,
        primaryKey: true,
        unique: 'userItemUnique',
    },
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use migrations for this.

Sequelize-cli provides a methods addConstraint and andIndex which can be used to achieve

From the [docs](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/migrations.html#addconstraint-tablename-attributes-options-)

```
queryInterface.addConstraint('Users', ['email'],
 { type: 'unique', name: 'custom_unique_constraint_name'
 });
```

Comment: Why do you have to add the constraint through Sequelize-cli? Is there no way to do it through Sequelize itself?

Comment: You can do this using indexes
[This]( https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/3468) issue details about it
Though it doesn&#39;t feel very clean way to do imo

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is still following this, I solved this by manually defining the foreign keys in the model where the unique constraint is required (you can still use sequelize association such as `.hasMany`).

Regarding your own code, I think there might be a confusion when you ask for `Assume that each user may only have one of each type of item` since you are not defining what is an item type.

I've drafted something with my own understanding and taking into account my previous comment.

```
User = Model.define('User', {
    id: {
        type: DataType.UUID,
        defaultValue: DataType.UUIDV1,
        primaryKey: true,
        allowNull: false,
        validate: {
          isUUID: 1,
        },
    },
});

Item = Model.define('Item', {
    id: {
        type: DataType.UUID,
        defaultValue: DataType.UUIDV1,
        primaryKey: true,
        allowNull: false,
        validate: {
          isUUID: 1,
        },
    },
    type: {
        type: DataType.STRING,
        unique: 'uniqueUserItemType' // see note 1
    }
    userId: { 
        type: DataType.UUID,
        references: { // see note 2
          model: User,
          key: 'id',
        },
        unique: 'uniqueUserItemType',
    }
});

User.hasMany(Item, {
    foreignKey: {
        allowNull: false,
        name: 'itemId',
    },
    onUpdate: 'cascade',
    onDelete: 'cascade',
});

Item.belongsTo(User);
```

I've also added a belongsTo association as recommended by Sequelize.

[1] More info on composite unique constraint [here](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/model-basics.html#column-options).

[2] More info on foreign key definition inside of model [here](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/assocs.html#implementation-3).

Comment: The only thing I would add is that once you create the foreign key manually in the definition you can use the indexes command like this........ indexes: [{ unique: true, fields: ['name','user_id'] }] to create the composite key and this creates it correctly from what I can see.  I will add an answer to show this in more detail soon

Answer (score 0):

In my case I did something like this based on Joel Barenco's answer.

```
const { Model, DataTypes } = require('sequelize');
const User = require('../models/user');

module.exports = function(sequelize){
    class Algorithm extends Model {}
    UserModel = User(sequelize);//@JA - Gets a defined version of user class

    var AlgorithmFrame = Algorithm.init({
        id: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            primaryKey: true,
            autoIncrement: true
        },
        name: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: false,
        },
        user_Id: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            references: { 
                model: UserModel,
                key: 'id',
            },
        }
    }, {
      sequelize,
      modelName: 'Algorithm',
      indexes: [{ unique: true, fields: ['name','user_id'] }]
    });

    return AlgorithmFrame
};
```

The idea here is to manually create the foreign key, but you can define the unique indexes instead with `indexes: [{ unique: true, fields: ['name','user_id'] }]`

My tactic also shows how to define the model in a class as well.  To call it you simply pass sequelize to it like this, where sequelize is the variable holding all your connection info etc...

```
const Algorithm = require('../models/algorithm');
const AlogorithmModel = Algorithm(sequelize);
```

then you can make sure it's created with

```
await AlogorithmModel.sync({ alter: true });
```

My user model file is this:

```
const { Model, DataTypes } = require('sequelize');
module.exports = function(sequelize){
    class User extends Model {}
    return User.init({
      id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true
      },
      name: {
          type: DataTypes.STRING,
          allowNull: false
      },
      trading_system_key: {
          type: DataTypes.STRING,
          allowNull: false
      },
    }, {
      sequelize,
      modelName: 'User',
      indexes: [{ unique: true, fields: ['trading_system_key'] }]
    });
};
```

Comment: The one thing I'm not sure how to do with this is control the onUpdate and onDelete if anyone figures that out let me know